# Javascript window.width and mobile display specification

Tags: javascript

I have a smartphone with display specification as 720x1280.
But, when I make a sample webpage and add javascript

```
window.width
```

I get 340.

Why is that?

Comment: Because a pixel is not a pixel. http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably look into ur view port, try adding this

```
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-    scalable=0;” />
```

that will ensure that ur document is will fill the device screen, essentially make one ccs pixel equal to one device pixel